How much nutrient does yeast need?
I am experimenting with adding yeast nutrients to my bread.  I have been using an egg, but to substitute for that I have tried lemon juice and marmite.  However I have no idea how much is likely to be enough.
What sorts of amounts of yeast nutrient that are commonly found in the kitchen are enough such that adding additional will not result in significantly more yeast activity?

I'm confused... you're trying to NOT increase yeast activity?

No, I want to add enough that the yeast are not slowed down by lack of nutrients, ie. when adding more will not make them metabolise faster.

but if you add nutrients to give them the right conditions they need, wouldn't they work faster?  I really don't understand what you're trying to do

Marmite is a yeast extract with added salt. It's basically the left-overs from brewing beer, which are then autolysed by addition of salt and cooked. There won't be much usable nutrients for your yeast in there other than some free amino-acids.

@bob1 and the salt will slow the yeast, I suspect

@Ecnerwal this should be an answer, not a comment!

Wheat flour all by itself provides plenty for yeast to grow on. "Yeast nutrient" (so-described) is almost exclusively associated with brewing; but it's not needed in either context, as the yeast will find plenty to grow on with flour or malt extract/wort. Straight sugar will wind them up, (though past a certain point it may actually retard them somewhat) but is not "yeast nutrient" in the common terminology.
In a broader view, most things that "speed up" fermentation are regarded as making worse-tasting bread than slow fermentation. i.e. warming the dough .vs. room temperature .vs. refrigerated.

Yeast nutrients are not widely used in beer brewing. They are considerably more important for wine and especially for mead, the substrates for which are deficient in nutrients.
